# json deserialize 2 nested list in c#

Tags: c#, json, list, nested, deserialization

I need to deserialize 2 nested loops.I can deserialize to data object but couldn't deserialize to orderDetails.

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "OrderId": "3",
        "OrderCode": "5",
        "OrderDetails": [
            {
                "ProductId": "12",
                "ProductCode": "T12",

            }
        ]
    }
 ]
}
```

My SalesTable class i am using this while i get data

```
[DataContract]
public class SalesTable
{
    [DataMember(Name = "OrderId")]
    public string OrderId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "OrderCode")]
    public string OrderCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "OrderDate")]
    public string OrderDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "OrderDetails")]
    public List<SalesLine> SalesLines { get; set; }

}
```

My SalesLine class i am using this while i get OrderDetails

```
[DataContract]
public class SalesLine
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ProductCode ")]
    public string ProductCode    { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Quantity")]
    public string Quantity { get; set; }

}
```

With below code i can get SalesTable but couldn't SalesLine,what should i do?

```
foreach (var obj in SalesHeader.SalesTables)
        {
            SalesTable salesTable = new SalesTable();
            salesTable.OrderId = obj.OrderId;
            salesTable.SalesLines = obj.SalesLines;
            foreach (var objDetail in salesTable.SalesLines)
            {
                SalesLine SalesLine = new SalesLine();
                SalesLine.ProductCode = objDetail.ProductCode;
            }


        }
```

Comment: Please also show the code that you tried for the deserialization.

Comment: I solved my problem,i made a mistake when i definion to productcode